# /dev/dsp windows alternative

Tags: c++, c, audio, windows

in Linux playing or recording some audio is just read or write /dev/dsp But how to do the same in windows ? (with C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no static device name, you should use `waveOut*` functions, [`here`](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3) is a nice example of using those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The **Media Control Interface (MCI)** provides standard commands for playing multimedia devices and recording multimedia resource files. These commands are a generic interface to nearly every kind of multimedia device.

You can open a device using MCI_OPEN and can send the command using mciSendCommand function. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743441%28VS.85%29.aspx for more details.

Or you can also use audio/video apis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663260%28v=VS.85%29.aspx